# Formula to find duplicates and print the number of mentions

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a formula determine duplicate values in a spreadsheet and count the number of mentions of each, then to sort into two cells.

Hoping it goes from something like this:

| Animal Type |
| --- |
| Cat |
| Dog |
| Parrot |
| Cat |
| Cat |
| Dog |
| Elephant |
| Elephant |

To something like this

| No. Animals | Animal Type |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Cat |
| 2 | Dog |
| 1 | Parrot |
| 1 | Elephant |

How would I go about that?

Comment: Try `countif`..

Answer (score 1):

Try Pivot table, It will also sort the values in descending order. .[image: Check the screen shot]